# Javascript execution in Adobe PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp in C# to read the pdf and fill values for text fields in it and based on one text field value, I'm trying to run javascript action to fill two other fields before saving the document.

I can see the script store in the pdf but it is not executing. Is there a better way to run the scripts in iTextSharp or in adobe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, iText does not have an Acrobat JavaScript engine.

In order to run (Acrobat) JavaScript in your form, you will have to open it in Acrobat/Reader, and provide a trigger to execute the scripts. Depending on which event the scripts are attached, you would either just have to run them (for example in the pageOpen event of the page on which the document opens), or using `this.calculateNow()` (again) in the pageOpen event of the page on which the document opens. If you have a multi-page document, you may also add a mechanism which runs those scripts only once (how to do that has been explained many times in many places (here on stackoverflow, but also in the Adobe forums, the AcrobatUsers forums (rest in peace), PlanetPDF etc.).

Comment: Debenu's Quick PDF Library (http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/features/) claims support for JavaScript and we at Datalogics have support for executing JavaScript similar to how Acrobat does it (depending on the version of Acrobat) but we only have support for this in our PDF Java Toolkit (http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdfjavatoolkit/)

Comment: @BrandonHaugen Ah, yeah, I should have remembere the PDF Java Toolkit…

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes, I tried to add triggers. I added the script under Calaculate. I also tried the "Set Document Actions" under Tools in Adobe but the script is not triggered when it runs through iTextSharp. I can trigger the script directly in Adobe and it is working as expected but when the pdf is read through iTextSharp it doesn't work.